# htaccess generic metjod to redirect path to file name

Tags: apache, .htaccess

please help to configure .htaccess for this requirement, I can't find this special case in the existing examples around:

```
http://localhost/project/x/y
```

should be rewritten to

```
http://localhost/project/_x_y.phtml
```

The typical examples are specified almost to be x and y fixed, I'm asking for a generic solution.

Any help appreciate.

Comment: _“I can't find this special case in the existing examples around”_ - well the point of an _example_ generally is that it does not have to be the 100% solution to each and every specific problem, but that it should illustrate the _principles_ involved to you. Sorry, but just going “meh, couldn’t find anything that I just need to copy&paste, so I’m gonna ask” is a bit lame, and below the minimum effort you are expected to put in.

Comment: Not looking for fixed, given strings of text, but doing _pattern matching_, is probably the most common use case in URL rewriting. If you’re saying you weren’t able to find _anything_ that could get you started here - sorry, but then I’m not buying that you made a reasonable effort in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put it in a .htaccess file (File without a name). Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?http://localhost/project/x/y$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/project/_x_y.phtml [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure that's what you meant.
https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/htaccess/

Comment: This rule would be only work for x=x and y=y. I'm struggle with it because x and y are unknown. I've tried $1, $2 or something like this but I didn't get it on for each possibility that would be come.

Comment: Good luck, I can' t help you anymore because I no more know about this.